# CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE never getting called in Fragment

Tags: android

Picking image from Gallery and using library to crop image

Language: Kotlin

Container: Fragment

```
private fun selectPhoto() {
    val galleryIntent = Intent()
    galleryIntent.type = "image/*"
    galleryIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Photo"), GALLERY_PICK)
}
```

CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE never getting called

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!!.data != null) {
        val imageUri = data.data
        Log.d("imageUri:", imageUri.toString()) // getting called
        CropImage.activity(imageUri)
            .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
            .start(context as Activity)
    }

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

        val result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data)
        Log.d("result:", result.toString()) // not getting called

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {

            val error = result.error
            Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() // not getting called

        }

    }

}
```

Log:

```
D/ViewRootImpl@683ba8c[CropImageActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@683ba8c[CropImageActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e9e30d9[MainActivity]: stopped(false) old=true
D/ViewRootImpl@e9e30d9[MainActivity]: stopped(false) old=false
D/ViewRootImpl@e9e30d9[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2340) new=(0,0,1080,2340) req=(1080,2340)0 dur=9 res=0x7 s={true 515972288512} ch=true
D/OpenGLRenderer: createReliableSurface : 0x78ab8a59c0, 0x7822585000
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/ViewRootImpl@683ba8c[CropImageActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@d08a7ce[CropImageActivity]
D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/ViewRootImpl@e9e30d9[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@79d574a[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@79d574a[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=92
D/FA: Connected to remote service
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x789be5be10 disconnect failed
D/ViewRootImpl@683ba8c[CropImageActivity]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2340) new=(0,0,1080,2340) req=(1080,2340)8 dur=24 res=0x5 s={false 0} ch=true
D/ViewRootImpl@683ba8c[CropImageActivity]: stopped(true) old=false
D/ViewRootImpl@683ba8c[CropImageActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: '47cbc17', fd=77
```

Kindly tell me what I'm missing ? This code works just fine in an Activity, but trying very first time in Fragment

To crop image, I'm using in app level gradle:

```
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
```

In AndroidManifest, I'm using:

```
<activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity" android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution

```
.start(it, this@FragmentOne)
```